# C++ how to convert unsigned char array to string?

Tags: c++, string, sha

I'm testing a piece of code that performs a hash operation (sha256) of a binary file and I've got something like this:

> `for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) printf("%02x", c[i]);`

This prints something like:

```
12b64492d18aa37d609f27cb02ce5ba381068d1ef5625193df68451c650a2b8d
```

I'm asking how can I do to get the string shown below into a string variable in C++.

thanks

Comment: If you like `printf`, there's `sprintf`.  If you like iostreams, there's stringstream.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```

```
std::ostringstream oss;
for(int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) 
{
      oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << +c[i];
}
auto str = oss.str();
```

Comment: Why `auto` rather than `string`?

Answer (score 1):

For printing out hex values, you can use `std::hex` format; for setting width and fill character, use `std::setw` and `std::setfill`, which are part of `<iomanip>`.
As you do not show the data type of `c`, I suppose/suggest to use an unsigned integral type, e.g. `unsigned char`. I slightly adapted the code to make it self contained):

```
#define SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH 256

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    unsigned char c[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        c[i]=i;

    std::stringstream ss;
    for(int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        ss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned int)c[i];
    }

    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

Output:

```
000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3d3e3f404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f606162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7d7e7f808182838485868788898a8b8c8d8e8f909192939495969798999a9b9c9d9e9fa0a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9aaabacadaeafb0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7b8b9babbbcbdbebfc0c1c2c3c4c5c6c7c8c9cacbcccdcecfd0d1d2d3d4d5d6d7d8d9dadbdcdddedfe0e1e2e3e4e5e6e7e8e9eaebecedeeeff0f1f2f3f4f5f6f7f8f9fafbfcfdfeff
```

Comment: This just prints the loop index, not the characters in the source array that the OP wants to convert...

Comment: @underscore_d: right; I just wanted to demonstrate the use of `std::hex`, and as OP does not specify the type of `c`, I rewrote that part. But: adapted answer now to make a suggestion on the type of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for comparison, here's the `sprintf` version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

std::string ss;
ss.resize(SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2 + 1); // includes space for terminating NUL
int used = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    used += sprintf(&ss[used], "%02x", c[i]);
ss.resize(used);
```

Note that there's no harm in making the buffer larger than necessary initially because the final exact size is used, but if there's any possibility the buffer is too small then one must use `snprintf` and also pass the buffer space remaining (`ss.size() - used`).

Comment: I would use a `char[]` to receive the formatted data, then construct a `string` from the `char[]`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: There's no advantage to that, `std::string` is a smart-pointer wrapper for a `char[]`, and even if you use a statically-sized local array, you still end up stuck with an extra copy.  The way I show is better.  For even more efficiency, scrap the `sprintf` call (which has to parse a format string) and just do two `char` assignments, corresponding to high- and low-nibble, directly into the `std::string`.

Comment: I guess technically a raw allocated array has the advantage that you can obtain space uniitialised then write what you want to it - whereas C++ containers require you to`resize()` and thus set some known value in the new capacity before just overwriting it, or `reserve()` then `emplace_`/`push_back()` piece by piece, making the library check `capacity`, increment `size`, etc each time. Still, I doubt it matters usually, so the extra safety and readability of the C++ versions win in such cases.